# can't get escape_javascript to work the way i want it to, rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

currently for school I am trying to build a Wikipedia type replica app and I am stuck on how to correctly use the escape_javascript method.  I have a wiki edit page where I would like to add/remove collaborators if the wiki has been checked as private.  Right now I'm using ajax to add/remove collaborators live without a page refresh (which is working), but I'm having problems trying to update the collaborators count live on the edit page.

Here is what I have so far:

collaborators_controller.rb:

```
class CollaboratorsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    Collaborator.create(wiki_id: params[:wiki_id], user_id: params[:user_id])

    render js: "$('#"+params[:user_id]+"').text('Remove');"
               "$('.js-collaborators-count').html('<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'wikis/count') %>');"
  end

  def destroy
    collab = Collaborator.find(params[:id])
    user_id = collab.user_id
    collab.destroy

    render js: "$('#"+user_id.to_s+"').text('Add');"
               "$('.js-collaborators-count').html('<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'wikis/count')) %>');"
  end
end
```

_count.html.erb

```
<%= pluralize(@wiki.collaborators.count, 'collaborator') %>
```

**UPDATE**

I altered my destroy action in collaborators_controller.rb and also created a destroy.js.erb file (I was hoping to get my destroy.js.erb view working before I tackled my create.js.erb view).  However, now I keep getting the following error no matter which line I go with involving an attempt to update the collaborators count (you'll see the other commented attempts below).

Server Log Error:
https://gist.github.com/jlquaccia/6c2ae2661d8cc15625f6

collaborators_controller.rb:

```
 def destroy
    @collab = Collaborator.find(params[:id])
    @user_id = @collab.user_id
    @collab.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.js
    end
  end
```

destroy.js.erb:

```
<% if @collab.destroyed? %>
  $('#'+<%= @user_id.to_s %>).text('Add');
  $('.js-collaborators-count').html("<%= pluralize(@wiki.collaborators.count, 'collaborator') %>");
  // $('.js-collaborators-count').html("<%= escape_javascript(pluralize(@wiki.collaborators.count, 'collaborator')) %>");
  // $('.js-collaborators-count').html("<%= raw escape_javascript(render partial: 'wikis/count') %>");
<% else %>
  $('#'+<%= @user_id.to_s %>).prepend("<div class='alert alert-danger'><%= flash[:error] = 'Oops something went wrong..' %></div>");
<% end %>
```

Comment: i think your count is not being displayed.? because you are trying to access this `$('js-collaborators-count')` but you havent use `.` or `#` so it wont be acessed. i think it is class or may be id.?

Comment: Oops good catch, it is a class :p But even after targeting the js-collaborators-count class properly, I am still unable to get the count to update live..

Comment: i want to suggest two things. 1)  please make `create.js.erb` and `destroy.js.erb` and do the rendering stuff there. Views are to display things. secondly try to use `raw` like this `$('.js-collaborators-count').html('<%= raw escape_javascript(render partial: 'wikis/count')) %>');` Lastly once you move the stuff to the view files. donot enclosed the things in `inverted` commas that might be one of the reason your change is not been displayed

Comment: Thanks, I tried reworking things like you said and feel as though I am close now, however I've run into a new roadblock.  See edit above.

Comment: so the error is that `@wiki` object does not exists. from your `destroy` action i cant see you have fetch the `@wiki` object. So please set the `@wiki` object please in that action or make before_filter/before_action to fetch that

Comment: Thank you!  That was all I needed, it works fine now!